# Proving the sequence $\left\{\frac{e^n-e^{-n}}{e^n+e^{-n}}\right\}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing

I am asked to show that the sequence $$\left\{\frac{e^n-e^{-n}}{e^n+e^{-n}}\right\}$$ converges using the definition of convergence. Thus, I am trying to do this by using the definition of convergence, i.e., I am looking for a value for $n$ that will make this true. However, I am having some trouble since this involves $e$.

I get to this point,

$$\frac{1}{e}<\frac{e^n+e^{-n}}{e^n-e^{-n}}$$

but I am not sure how to continue to get $n$ by itself. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you figured out what the limit is yet? Without knowing the limit, you'll have a hard time using the definition to prove convergence.

Comment: @carmichael561 No, the question just states to use the definition of convergence to prove this,

Comment: Ok, but what I'm saying is: before trying to prove anything, figure out what the limit "should be".

Comment: @carmichael561 Yes, I see. I am just not sure how to do this.

Comment: If you divide the numerator and denominator by $e^n$, the result is $\frac{1-e^{-2n}}{1+e^{-2n}}$. And $e^{-2n}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. So the limit is $1$.

Comment: @carmichael561 sad that the tag won't work

Comment: Your title does not match the body of your question...

Comment: One of the ways can be using the definition of tanhx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that as @carmichael561 said, you really need to find what this tends to in order to figure out an $n$ for which 
$$
\bigg|\frac{e^n-e^{-n}}{e^n+e^{-n}} -L\bigg|<\epsilon
$$
fortunately it's not too hard to figure out $L=1$. Then we work backwards as usual 
$$
\bigg|\frac{e^n-e^{-n}}{e^n+e^{-n}} -1\bigg|<\epsilon\implies 
\bigg|\frac{-2e^{-n}}{e^n+e^{-n}}\bigg|<\epsilon\\
\implies 2e^{-n}<\epsilon (e^n+e^{-n})\implies \frac{2}{\epsilon}<\frac{e^n+e^{-n}}{e^{-n}}\\
\implies \frac{2}{\epsilon}<e^{2n}+1
$$
then we see that we can take 
$$
n>\log(\sqrt{2/\epsilon-1})
$$
which will make sense as long as we take $\epsilon<2$.

If $\epsilon>2$, any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ will do. Note the intuition behind this, the sequence is bounded between $0$ and $1$, thus, any value will be within $2$ of $1$ trivially.

Answer (score 0):

The limit is $1$. Let's try to solve, for $m> 0$:

$$\bigg|\frac{1-e^{-2n}}{1+e^{-2n}} -1\bigg|< 10^{-m}$$

I don't really know but if I remember correctly if $x > 0 $

$$-2x(1-x) <\frac{1-x }{ 1+x  } - 1  = \frac{-2x }{ 1+x  }  < 
-2x 
$$

So if we set $2x = e^{-2n}<10^{-m}$ we are done.